# How to wait for all stream results and return final result as object?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm new to rxjs and here is a simple question that I came across recently. I am trying to loop an array with a Promise utility. My expectation is to wait for all stream results and the end of the stream and return it as an object. However, I am not sure how to combine all the stream and return them as a single object.

I have already tried `toArray()`, i think this is the most nearest answer that I want, but i hope that there will be some operator that is similar as `toArray()` like `toObject()`. I know there is one operator called `forkJoin()`, but im not sure how it can be used in my case.

Here is my code

```
const textList = [
  {
    key: "text1key",
    label: "text1"
  },
  {
    key: "text2key",
    label: "text2"
  },
  {
    key: "text3key",
    label: "text3"
  }
];

const myPromise = (data) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve("translated" + data);
})

const source = from(textList).pipe(
  concatMap(textObj =>
    myPromise(textObj.label).then(result => ({ key: textObj.key, value: result }))),
  map(({ key, value }) => ({ [key]: value })),
  toArray(),  // expect to return a single object instead of array.
);

source.subscribe(finalResult => console.log("FINAL RESULT", finalResult));
```

Expect to get object during subscription instead of an array.

Comment: Probably you need use reduce instead of map

Comment: ArtemArkhipov yup, you are right, I am not aware of it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to user `reduce` instead of `map` and `toArray`. So import the `reduce` operator and change code to the following:

```
const textList = [
  {
    key: "text1key",
    label: "text1"
  },
  {
    key: "text2key",
    label: "text2"
  },
  {
    key: "text3key",
    label: "text3"
  }
];

const myPromise = (data) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve("translated" + data);
})

const source = from(textList).pipe(
  concatMap(textObj =>
    myPromise(textObj.label).then(result => ({ key: textObj.key, value: result }))),
  reduce((acc, {key, value}) => {
    acc[key] = value; // add key and value into accum
    return acc;  // return accum for the next iteration
  }, {}) // set an initial value (accum) as empty object
);

source.subscribe(finalResult => console.log("FINAL RESULT", finalResult)); // { translatedtext1Key: text1, ... }
```

Reduce takes a callback function where accumulated value is a first argument and array item as a second one. It is very similar to how `reduce` works with simple arrays.
You can read more about it [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-reduce).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want. I didn't notice that there is a `reduce` in rxjs operators.